# Java and XML : hack to avoid back-compatibility

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c

Is there an XML keyword that is interpreted by default as "end of XML" or similar (can be crash) but who can also be identified and ignored, this in w3c.dom standard?

*Why?*

I have added some functionalities to an existing program. These functionalities do add information to an XML source file representing a project.

The additional data are ignored by an old version of the program. The problem is that if they open a project with an old version and save it, the additional information will disappear.

What I want to do, is ensure a new source file cannot be opened by an old version of the program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to do this without also modifying the older version of the project.  I guess I would do one of a few things:

1. Refactor the program so it doesn't blow away the portions it doesn't understand.
2. Verify the XML with a .xsd and immediately stop running if it doesn't match what is expected.
3. Add a version attribute to the root tag of your XML file to check prior to running.

Comment: The problem here is about the software distribution, I have no way to ensure that all users get the new version.

Comment: I agree... this is a tough nut.  As I said though, I can't think of a way to do this without modifying the older version anyway.  Either they need to take your new version or the modified old one.

Answer (score 1):

No, there really isn't any simple magic you can add after the fact.

The usual way one solves this problem is to design the document from the outset to carry a version number, and to design applications to check that version number and understand that they may not be able to preserve versions more recent than they were designed for.

Another approach would be to design from the outset to validate against a DTD or schema, so that any new element introduced would make the document invalid for the older version of the program.

I can think of some ugly ways to kluge around this, but they would involve making the file no longer be a well-formed XML document. (Make it a Document Fragment, for example, with multiple root elements. Or, if the old code was compiled with a parser which only supports XML 1.0, require that new documents be written as XML 1.1.) Of course those too would make the document unreadable by the old code.

Basically, all the *good* answers require releasing a bugfix for the old code, and the lesson to learn is "plan for growth." I wish I could tell you otherwise.

Comment: I wish I would have designed this program from scratch, unfortunately I didn't. Legacy has always been a pain in software engineering :s I retain the "well formed XML breakdown" solution but still have hope for another answer :D thanks! @jgitter thanks too for your answers

Comment: In that case, moving new versions of the document to XML 1.1 is the cleanest thought I've got at the moment. Good luck...

Comment: It seems effectively to be a good idea, sadly the old version is already 1.1 compliant.

Comment: Dunno what to tell ya then, Boss. Can you set any of the contents of the document to something which will cause the old code to panic?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do, is ensure a new source file cannot be opened by an old version of the program.

That's the other way round from the usual requirement, which is to ensure that a new file CAN be read by an old program.

I would have thought it is relatively easy to find some way of changing the data so that the old code will crash or fail, for example by changing the namespace.

Comment: Effectively, it was too mainstream for me :p I will explore this way, sadly (or not ?) the data parser is quite well written and handles a lot of errors. So I will search through this to find a way to make it crash an "elegant" way.